# Swap two booleans in array

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I have an array of boolean values.
Now I need swap item from position1 with item from position2 ;

I use this void

```
public static void swap(boolean x, boolean z){
   writeln("swapping");
   boolean temp = x;
   x=z;
   z=temp;
}
```

and

```
swap(position[a],position[moves[b]);
```

but it don't work. Just not swap.
Any ideas?

Comment: params here are passed by value and not by reference

Comment: what doesn't work ? explain... what are the unexpected results you are getting? what are you giving as parameters?

Comment: pointers arent used in Java to access variable over function, possible answer is just place global variable **position**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you need to do:

```
public static void swap(boolean[] arr, int x, int z){    
    writeln("swapping");
    boolean temp = arr[x];
    arr[x]=arr[z];
    arr[z]=temp;    
}
```

because when you send `position[a]` and `position[b]` java will copy their value to a new parameter, and so when you leave the `swap` function, no change was done to the variables

to understand more you can read on pass-by-value and pass-by-ref in java [here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)

> When the method or constructor is invoked, the values of the
>   actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter
>   variables, each of the declared Type, before execution of the body of
>   the method or constructor. The Identifier that appears in the
>   DeclaratorId may be used as a simple name in the body of the method or
>   constructor to refer to the formal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array and 2 indexes

```
public static void swap(boolean[] arr, int index1, int index2){
    writeln("swapping");
    boolean temp = arr[index1];
    arr[index1]=arr[index2];
    arr[index2]=temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing simple types - and u can't change their values.
Try

```
public static void swap(boolean[] arr, int index1, int index2){
    writeln("swapping");
    boolean temp = arr[index1];
    arr[index1]=arr[index2];
    arr[index2]=temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java only passes by value, you can swap elements in an array doing:

```
public static void swap(boolean[] a, int index1, int index2) {
    boolean tmp = a[index1];
    a[index1] = a[index2];
    a[index2] = tmp;
}
```

and you can call it:

```
swap(position, a, moves[b]);
```